# How to resolve "No Space" Error when trying to gem install rails in ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rubygems, out-of-memory, virtualbox

I am trying to install rails on my Virtual Box Ubuntu when I got the "No Space left on device error"

[image]

I ran a couple of commands to check the device space and it does seem that I still have space left

I am looking at /dev/sda1 and I have 46% of space left.
[image]

Same here. I seem to still have 60% INode free for usage.
[image]

Can anyone advise why I am hitting this error? Am I looking at the wrong memory data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inode for `/dev/loop0` reached 100%. You need to find directory with unusual big files count, for example, this will print files count

```
for i in /*; do echo $i; find $i | wc -l; done
```

Then fix issue with files. It may be log or session files.

Comment: What is dev/loop0 used for? When I want to install rails, shouldn't it be looking at my dev/sda1 storage size?

Comment: I think that rofs is folder where your virtual box ubuntu filesystem mounted

Comment: Oh, so what about dev/sda1 then?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know. But to resolve your issue look at `dev/loop0`

Comment: I found a couple of directories that have a lot of files for example /rofs/var/spool/rsyslog. However when I try to rm -rf the directory, it doesn't allow me. Saying that it's a read-only file system. How do I get ard this?

Comment: Try to remove immutable bit `chattr -i`. To list attributes use `lsattr`